# How do I get an html object nodelist's value into my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

I have an object nodeList in HTML, I didn't create this I'm just maintaining it, and it produces a certain value when placed inside a div. That's the value I want. From *there*, I'm able to call on the div ID and get the inner HTML, but I don't *want* the div to exist solely to get the value I need. Is there a way to get that value without having it inside a div? Or do I have to just use the div and find a way to hide it from the page?

The only reason I know it's a object nodelist is because when I getElementByName, and put it into another div, it says "object Nodelist". Thanks guys

Comment: You can create a DOM node with createElement() and append the div to it, without appending that container to the page.

Comment: That sounds like it would work. Can you type a line or two to give an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: It's not technically an "object nodeList". It's a container of "nodes". A node is a generic term for a piece of the HTML DOM tree (or in an XML document, a piece of the XML DOM tree). Nodes come in different types (element, attribute, comment, text, etc.). As far as the JavaScript runtime is concerned, however, it's just a type of object and that's why you see it reported as "object nodeList". You should provide us with the relevant code so we can give you more concise answers.

Comment: The line in question is something like

<div><#ROOM field="RoomNumber"/</div>

and the div will show something like 1205-A

Comment: `var wrapper = document.createElement('div'); wrapper.appendChild( yourNodeListReference );`

Comment: would "yourNodeListReference" be RoomNumber or ROOM[RoomNumber], or something to that effect?